# Inserting data into Google Sheets from a DataFrame according to the values of the table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get data from the site. Then I build a DF in which I format the data so that it can then be worked with in google tables.
After that, I'm trying to upload the data to google sheets.

I can do

```
    wks.set_data frame(df_res.T, 'A1')
```

and this will insert the DF into the cells starting from A1.

But I have a problem with the fact that it is necessary not just to insert information from the data table into the table, but to do it according to the values from the table

```
|names |col2 |col3 |col4 |    Area for data frame   |
|----|----|----|----|----|----|
|a|1|2|3|||
|b|1|2|3|||
|c|1|2|3|||
|d|1|2|3|||
|e|1|2|3|||
|f|1|2|3|||
|g|1|2|3|||
```

Area for data frame - the area of the table in which there are several columns.

data that i get from site

```
|name |col1 |col2 |col3|
|----|----|-----|-----|
|c|data|data|data|
|d|data|data|data|
|f|data|data|data|
|g|data|data|data|
```

gs_res

```
|names |col2 |col3 |col4 |    Area for data frame   |
|----|----|----|----|----|----|
|a|1|2|3|||
|b|1|2|3|||
|c|1|2|3|data from df||
|d|1|2|3|data from df||
|e|1|2|3|||
|f|1|2|3|data from df||
|g|1|2|3|data from df||
```

The number of "names" in the DF may be less than in Google Sheet.
I was thinking of getting data from a Google table in a data frame and after inserting data into it from the second DF, transfer the resulting DF to the Google table. But you will have to build a table from scratch every time.